# Scala no class def error on running Spark program with Kafka integrations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have the following dependency versions

```
    <storm.version>1.0.2</storm.version>
    <kafka.version>0.9.0.1</kafka.version> <!--  0.8.2.2/0.9.0.1 --> 
    <spark.version>1.6.2</spark.version>
    <scala.lib.version>2.11.7</scala.lib.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
```

I use eclipse Luna as my runtime env.
However, when I run my spark program (with kafka), I see the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
at kafka.utils.Pool.<init>(Pool.scala:28)
at kafka.consumer.FetchRequestAndResponseStatsRegistry$.<init>(FetchRequestAndResponseStats.scala:60)
```

It seems that this is problem because of scala version w.r.t kafka and spark. Ive tried updating scala versions 2.10.6, 2.11.7, 2.11.8 in the pom, but of no difference. Any suggestions please?
Thanks

Comment: Default Scala version for 1.6.2 is 2.10. Are you sure you use 2.11 cluster?

Comment: Spark Streaming 1.6.2 is compatible with Kafka 0.8.2.1.  And spark 1.6.2 uses scala-2.10 . https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/streaming-programming-guide.html#linking